# What is the person buying?

Tags: riddle

In an interview I was asked the below puzzle as the last question:

> A person goes to a shop to buy something and the ensuing conversation with the shopkeeper is mentioned below...
>
> Person: How much does one cost?
> Shopkeeper: It is Rs10.
> Person: How much for 14?
> Shopkeeper: Rs20.
> Person: How much for 114?
> Shopkeeper: Rs30.
>
> **What is the person trying to buy?**

I couldn't answer. Still figuring it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic puzzle. I was so sure that it must already have been asked here on Puzzling, but I have been unable to find a duplicate after a short keyword search ([this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86041/price-discrimination) question is perhaps the closest...). The answer is:

> **house numbers** (i.e. the usually metallic numerals that can be mounted on a wall or fence to indicate the house number). Usually, these are costed at a certain price per digit - in the case of your question, Rs10 for a single digit.
>
>  [image: House numbers]
>
>  This way, one numeral (e.g. for a house numbered 1-9) costs Rs10. But the *two numerals* required for a house numbered '14' would cost Rs20 (2 times Rs10, for a 1 and a 4) and the total cost of *three numerals* for a house numbered '114' would be Rs30 (3 times Rs10, for two 1s and a 4).